# what initializations i need to do in .lcf(linker file) and other files before generation RAM.bin image file for MPC5604E controller

Tags: c

I am trying to load the **RAM.bin** image on **SRAM** of MPC5604E controller through serial boot (using autobaud mode for LINFLEX0). I am using an sample LED toggle program to generate  **RAM.bin** image file and tried to load through serial boot, it is loaded successfully and LED toggle working fine(when watchdog is enabled),but if we disable the watchdog and then load and execute it,LED toggle is not working. So I assume there may be some issue  related to initialization in **.lcf**(linker file) and some other files before generating the **RAM.bin** file through code warrior for serial booting.

Can anybody help me with these initializations because i don't know what to do ? So that my **RAM.bin** image file can execute successfully.

MPC5604E.lcf :::

```
       /* lcf file for MPC5604E processors                                         */
       /*                                                                          */
       /*              512KB Flash, 96KB SRAM                                      */




      MEMORY
      {
            resetvector:           org = 0x00000000,   len = 0x00000008
            init:                  org = 0x00000020,   len = 0x00000FE0 
            exception_handlers:    org = 0x00001000,   len = 0x00001000
            internal_flash:        org = 0x00002000,   len = 0x000FE000

            internal_ram:          org = 0x40000000,   len = 0x00016000
            heap  :                org = 0x40016000,   len = 0x00001000
            stack :                org = 0x40017000,   len = 0x00001000

         }

         /* This will ensure the rchw and reset vector are not stripped by the linker*/
         FORCEACTIVE { "bam_rchw" "bam_resetvector" }

        SECTIONS
        {
          .__bam_bootarea LOAD (0x00000000): {} > resetvector

       GROUP : {
        .init LOAD (0x00000020) : {}
       .init_vle (VLECODE) LOAD (_e_init) : {
       *(.init)
       *(.init_vle)
       }
     } > init

     GROUP : {
     .ivor_branch_table (VLECODE) LOAD (0x00001000) : {}
      .__exception_handlers  (VLECODE) LOAD (_e_ivor_branch_table) : {} 
      } > exception_handlers

     GROUP  : {
     .text : {} 
     .text_vle (VLECODE) ALIGN(0x08): {
        *(.text)
      *(.text_vle)
     }
      .rodata (CONST) : {
       *(.rdata)
       *(.rodata)
      }
      .ctors : {}
      .dtors : {}
      extab : {}
      extabindex : {}
      } > internal_flash

      GROUP : {
       .__uninitialized_intc_handlertable ALIGN(2048) : {}
       .data   : {}
       .sdata  : {}
       .sbss   : {}
       .sdata2 : {}
       .sbss2  : {}
       .bss    : {}
       } > internal_ram
      }

      /* Freescale CodeWarrior compiler address designations */

     _stack_addr = ADDR(stack)+SIZEOF(stack);
     _stack_end  = ADDR(stack);
     _heap_addr  = ADDR(heap);
     _heap_end   = ADDR(heap)+SIZEOF(heap);


    /* Exceptions Handlers Location (used in Exceptions.c IVPR initialization)*/

    EXCEPTION_HANDLERS    = ADDR(exception_handlers);

   /* L2 SRAM Location (used for L2 SRAM initialization) */

   L2SRAM_LOCATION = 0x40000000;
```

Comment: Why would you want to deactivate the watchdog ? Anyway, you will need to give us the lcf file as well as the readelf/objdump files from the executable to understand the control flow of your boot.

Comment: @georgesl......we have to deactivate the watchdog for proper working of interfaces like uart.lcf and RAM.bin files written below:

Comment: @georgesl ....i have added the .lcf lines above....u can see the code above.But how can i add binary file???because it contain only data bytes...

Comment: there is nothing wrong apparently with your linker script. Could you add the bootloader (usually in assembly) ? for the bin file, you can always paste it on paste.org. I assume CodeWarrior is using some fork of gcc to compile  : you can also execute "gcc-objdump -b binary --adjust-vma=0x00000020 -D file.bin" to decompile your bin ( the vma adress is the starting point of the executable)